# How to find an object's locational displacement in Blender using Python?

Tags: python, animation, scripting, transforms

I'm trying to find displacement of animated objects between the first and end frame of an animation and then changing the color of objects based on their displacements. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want it to update at the end of the transform/animation or dynamically per frame during the transform/animation?

Comment: Actually I want to know that how much dislocation happened for each of objects during the animation and then changing the objects color based on this displacement. then I want add a legend which shows each color is representative of a rage of displacement.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l4S21GYIedk&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a driver based approach

Define a function `interp` which maps a value from one range to another, in this case the displacement range to 0,1 used for color.  Copy this script and run it in the text editor.

```
import bpy
def interp(value, f, t):
    m = (value - f[0]) / (f[1] - f[0])
    return t[0] + m * (t[1] - t[0])

#register it in the driver namespace

bpy.app.driver_namespace["interp"] = interp
```

Now if we look at an object that moves from (1.0, 0.0, 3.0) in frame 1 to (100.0, -199.0, 0.0) in last frame. Add a driver into the red color field field by typing

```
#interp(frame, [1.0, 100.0], [0.0, 1.0])
```

straight into the field, the # tells it to interpret it as a driver.  Could do this for r, g, b for x, y, z.  If you use object.color then you can do this quickly on each object, otherwise you will need  to create a material for each object.

Once you have made a driver it can be copied and pasted to other fields, requiring only to edit the location range. If you have zillions of objects probably pay to write a script, or request help on writing one to automate the creation of drivers.

Comment: Thanks all for your kind. Actually I'm a biginner in using scripts but I used your Script and run it but nothing happend in material. I want to know that how much dislocation happend for objects during the animation  and then changing the objects color based on this displacement. then I want add a legend which shows each color is representative of a rage of displacement

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l4S21GYIedk&feature=youtu.be